# Драйвер для Radeon под Debian stretch

Tags: linux, debian, gpu, radeon, xorg

Являюсь счастливым обладателем ноутбука с Radeon HD 7640G. До обновления использовал `fglrx`. Теперь его нету, Catalyst с сайта AMD не поддерживает актуальную версию `xorg`, а AMDGPU не поддерживает мою карточку. В результате VirtualBox Genymotion и AVD в плачевном состоянии.
Что можно сделать кроме отката до прошлой версии Debian?

Comment: Вот тут были? https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo Пакеты `firmware-linux-nonfree libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-video-ati firmware-amd-graphics` стоят?

Comment: Были. Все стоят. Сам драйвер определяется как "radeon".

Comment: только ждать нового каталиста. у меня на одном компе всё ещё стоит Джесси, а на втором пришлось отключить acpi

Comment: Поставить нормальную операционную систему, и не мучаться.